# How can I show post excerpts on the tags page?

Tags: tags, excerpt

I want to see excerpts on my tags page (e.g., http://domain.com/wp/?tag=psychotherapy), rather than the full length post. How do I do this?

I see the following in the tags.php page for my theme:

```
                // Start the Loop.
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                    /*
                     * Include the post format-specific template for the content. If you want to
                     * use this in a child theme, then include a file called called content-___.php
                     * (where ___ is the post format) and that will be used instead.
                     */
                    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

                endwhile;
                // Previous/next page navigation.
                twentyfourteen_paging_nav();
```

Do I replace the `get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );` line with something else, or do I have to create a content-post.php (or something like that). I do not see a content-post.php in the 2014 theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show post excerpts on my tags page, you will need to make changes in `content.php`. By default `content.php` uses post excerpts for search pages only but you can modify the default behavior.

This is how you can include tag pages to show post excerpts. Add `|| is_tag()` as follows:

```
<?php if ( is_search() || is_tag() ) : ?>
<div class="entry-summary">
  <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div><!-- .entry-summary -->
<?php else : ?>
<div class="entry-content">
  <?php
    the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentyfourteen' ) );
    wp_link_pages( array(
      'before'      => '<div class="page-links"><span class="page-links-title">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentyfourteen' ) . '</span>',
      'after'       => '</div>',
      'link_before' => '<span>',
      'link_after'  => '</span>',
    ) );
  ?>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

If you want to use post excerpt for categories, tags and author pages then better use `is_archive()` instead of `is_tag()` in above code.

Comment: @Doug good catch. Yes it was suppose to be `OR`.